# Sort downloads by domain name automatically, in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, download-manager

Is there a way to force images and executables to automatically download into separate folders in Firefox?

I found [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4781), but it doesn't work when I right-click-->*save image as*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several months later, I found an even better solution.

1. Install the [Shelve](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8282/) firefox addon
2. Add a new shelf (`tools -> addons -> Shelve -> options -> new`).  Edit the shelf, and set the *"Filename Template"* to the folder you want to save your images to, appended with `%{hostbasename}\%{filename}`.  For instance, mine is

   ```
   C:\Users\BlueRaja\Downloads\Images\%{hostbasename}\%{filename}
   ```
3. In the auto-save tab, under *"Save a document to this shelf if the URL matches this RegExp"*, set it to `.*(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif|tiff|exif)`
4. Any time you want to save an image, just right-click it and choose *"Shelve image"* (and for links: *"Shelve link"*).  It will automatically get saved and sorted by domain name, without so much as an annoying confirmation dialog!

Answer (score 1):

Try [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/howto/features/).

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [Download Sort](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/download-sort/).